# Cut (verb) - to reduce or to remove/stop

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, verbs

Context: Doctor asks me to ***cut*** smoking.

Dictionary says that cut when being used by itself means to ***reduce*** (in size/amount). However, it could also mean to ***remove*** (parts from a film, book, speech).

I also did a quick google search on ***"cut smoking"*** and ***"cut the habit"***. I found that cut is being taken to mean either ***reduce smoking/habit*** or ***to kick a habit*** (as in totally drop it)

So my question is can the word ***cut*** be taken to mean either reducing  kicking? or does it strictly only mean reducing and kicking is a wrong usage?

Thanks.

Comment: Reduce smoking is still smoking though to a lesser extent. I’d assume a doctor would recommend cut (stop) smoking definitely, though gradually.

Comment: A doctor wouldn't say that, because the advice is vague. He or she would say, "cut out" and mean "eliminate", or "cut down" to refer to lessening the amount of smoking. English really isn't about weirdo sentences that could mean multiple things.

Comment: So can i then conclude that "Cut Smoking" could mean both reduce smoking and eliminate smoking completely? Hence, i should i always use it with preposition such as cut back on (reduce) and cut out (eliminate) to bring clarity?

Comment: OP, basically yes. When the sentence is vague, don't use it. Clarify it -- in this case, with prepositions.

Answer (score 0):

To *cut* in this context means to *cut out* as in remove or eliminate smoking. In the context of film making or TV the word *cut* is just that. There is also to *cut down* which is to reduce. Since it is often hard to quit smoking then reduction is all that can be achieved. The phrase "Kick the habit" was used to encourage smokers to quit. It has since been used to mean stop or quit whatever habit or problem you may have.

Best source I could find https://www.theidioms.com/kick-the-habit/